# C# / SQL Server : datetime The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, datetime2

Database table column data type is `datetime`.

C# code my property type is `DateTime`

but I get an error

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated.